# How does typeahead apply CSS

Tags: typeahead, typeahead.js

Does typeahead come with a separate CSS file OR is (default) styling applied another way?

NOTE: I found a lot of CSS examples online (most define several .tt-* classes), but on the project itself (github) none of this

Comment: Your question is not clear for me.

Comment: I only found a JavaScript file, no CSS file. So I wonder: how is the necessary CSS defined and applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeahead.js defines its default styles in a javascript object.

The source is in a file called *css.js* which you can find [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/src/typeahead/css.js).

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. So CSS settings are stored/defined in JavaScript objects, and by means of JavaScript applied directly on the Typeahead elements (which are also created and inserted by means of JavaScript)